# Regarding OCaml Pattern Matching Syntax

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I am following [this](https://try.ocamlpro.com/) OCaml tutorial.

They provided the two functions below and said that they are equivalent.

```
let string_of_int x = match x with
   | 0 -> "zero"
   | 1 -> "one"
   | 2 -> "two"
   | _ -> "many"

let string_of_int2 = function
    | 0 -> "zero"
    | 1 -> "one"
    | 2 -> "two"
    | _ -> "many"
```

My query is regarding the syntax of the above functions.

1. I wrote the same function but instead of `| 0 ->` I simply did `0 ->` and the function still works in the same way. Is there any particular reason that the tutorial added the extra `|` in their function?
2. In the second function what is the use of the `function` keyword and why was this keyword absent in the first function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Some people think it looks nicer and more organized, and it allows you to change the order of cases using cut & paste without having to worry about which one didn't have the `|`.
2. The `function` syntax is an abbreviation: `function [CASES]` is the same as `fun x -> match x with [CASES]`. There is a subtle difference, which is with `function` it is not possible to shadow another variable by the name of the parameter.

   `let string_of_int x = [EXP]` is itself an abbreviation for `let string_of_int = fun x -> [EXP]`.

   So, to a close approximation, the "canonical" syntax uses `fun` and `match`, everything else is sugar. If you apply these two expansions to the two versions of the function, you will see that the same code results (modulo alpha-equivalence, of course :) ).